# How to have different app icon versions according to the version of Android?

Tags: android, icons, version

In the AndroidManifest you define the path of your app icon like this

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    ...
>
```

But how do I manage to change the icon according to the Android version of the phone ?
The design change according to the OS (it should be round with api 25, square with round corners with api < 25), and I can't find how to manage providing a different icon when needed.

I tried naming the mipmap folder like this :

[image: attempt]

But this doesn't work.

I didn't find anything about this on google, expect building different APK for different API version... but it is a bit overkill just for an app icon, right ?

Comment: use vector drawable images

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:roundIcon` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. In this case round icon will be used for sdk >= 25.